# How can I search for columns related to DataTables?

Tags: laravel, datatable

I have the following table:

[DataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaL6G.png)

The field "placa" is a relation of the tables "maintenance" and "vehicles", when I try to search by means of a data from the field "placa" the datatable does not return results, how can I solve it?

Controller code:

```
public function mantenimientoData()
{
    $mantenimiento = Mantenimiento::all();

    return Datatables()
            ->eloquent(Mantenimiento::query())
            ->addColumn('placa', function($mantenimiento){
                if ($mantenimiento->vehiculo_id) {
                    return $mantenimiento->vehiculos->placa;
                } else {
                    return 'N/A';
                }
            })
            ->addColumn('btn', 'mantenimientos.actions')
            ->rawColumns(['btn'])
            ->make(true);
}
```

My view:

```
var table = $("#mantenimientos-table").DataTable({
                serverSide: true,
                pageLength: 10,
                ajax: '{!! route('datatables.mantenimientos') !!}',
                columns: [
                    { data: 'nro_ficha', name: 'nro_ficha' },
                    { data: 'placa', name: 'placa' },
                    { data: 'fecha_ingreso', name: 'fecha_ingreso' },
                    { data: 'fecha_egreso', name: 'fecha_egreso' },
                    { data: 'estado', name: 'estado'  },
                    { data: 'valor_total', name: 'valor_total'  },
                    { data: 'btn', name: 'btn',orderable:false,serachable:false,sClass:'text-center' }
                ],
            });
```

Maintenance Model:

```
class Mantenimiento extends Model
{

   public function vehiculos()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(Vehiculo::class, 'vehiculo_id');
   }

}
```

and finally Vehicles Model:

```
class Vehiculo extends Model
{

   public function mantenimientos()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(Mantenimiento::class);
   }

}
```

Sorry for my bad English, but in Spanish I couldn't find help

Comment: Do you use a package for the table? Like `vue-tables-2`?

Comment: i dont @Commander

Comment: @Commander He's using the [Laravel Datatables](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master) package, which renders the chart server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by applying a ***join*** as follows.

In my controller:

```
public function mantenimientoData()
{
    $mantenimientos = Mantenimiento::join('vehiculos', 'vehiculos.id', '=', 'mantenimientos.vehiculo_id')
                        ->select('vehiculos.id', 'vehiculos.placa', 'mantenimientos.nro_ficha',
                                'mantenimientos.fecha_ingreso', 'mantenimientos.fecha_egreso',
                                'mantenimientos.estado', 'mantenimientos.valor_total');

    return Datatables::of($mantenimientos)
        ->addColumn('btn', 'mantenimientos.actions')
        ->rawColumns(['btn'])
        ->make(true);
}
```

Then in my view script:

```
var table = $("#mantenimientos-table").DataTable({
                serverSide: true,
                pageLength: 10,
                ajax: '{!! route('datatables.mantenimientos') !!}',
                columns: [
                    { data: 'nro_ficha', name: 'mantenimientos.nro_ficha' },
                    { data: 'placa', name: 'vehiculos.placa' },
                    { data: 'fecha_ingreso', name: 'mantenimientos.fecha_ingreso' },
                    { data: 'fecha_egreso', name: 'mantenimientos.fecha_egreso' },
                    { data: 'estado', name: 'mantenimientos.estado'  },
                    { data: 'valor_total', name: 'mantenimientos.valor_total'  },
                    { data: 'btn', name: 'btn',orderable:false,serachable:false,sClass:'text-center' }
                ]
            });
```

I share the solution that helped me in case someone else needs it